# Angular 2 MaterializeCSS Javascript function not called

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

I am having an issue with my Dropdown menu not working. The dropdown has 2 elements but it is not showing me any of the options. I believe that this is an issue with my Javascript, but I am not sure why it would not work since it is the .js and .css file straight from NPM and MaterializeCSS. Here is an image of what it looks like currently:

[image]

Here is some of my code:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 Project</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <link href="app/app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>


    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules\materialize-css\dist\js\materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <pm-app>Loading App...</pm-app>

</body>

</html>
```

**systems.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      "materialize-css": "npm:materialize-css",
      "angular2-materialize": "npm:angular2-materialize",

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      "materialize": {
        "main": "dist/js/materialize"
      }
    }

  });
})(this);
```

**welcome.component.html** (The page pictured above)

```
<h1>Eddie's PA Emporium</h1>

<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a materialize='dropdown' class='dropdown-button btn' href='javascript:void(0);' data-activates='options'>
    This is a dropdown
</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='options' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
<p><a href="/categories">Choose a Category</a></p>
<p><a href="/products">See all of our PA Inventory</a></p>
```

Also, a little extra question, but the StickyFooter modifications that I made in the MaterializeCSS .css file does not work correctly either. I have a feeling it is a similar reason to why my .js file is not working.

Thanks in advance!

**Still looking for a solution!

Comment: "node_modules\materialize-css\dist\js\materialize.min.js" the slash should be other way round i think. check your index.html file with materialize include path.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I created an environment here and did some debug. The problem is materialize js is loaded in index.html. However, your component is loaded after that happened. That is why it did not create the drop down automatically. You need to add this into your welcome.component.ts.

```
import { ..., AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class WelcomeComponent {

    ...

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check and see if this works when I get back and let you know how it goes!